# How Do I Convert Test Scores into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, file, io

I am tasked with creating a program that reads a .txt file of numbers, determines the size of the array, reopens the .txt file, and fills the array with the file's contents.  I'm looking for a solution that only uses "import java.util.* ; import java.io.* ;" to read the file and build the array with no other types of imports.  That is to say, keep it simple for me.  I don't know enough Java to make use of anything fancy.  I'm not supposed to use a fixed size for the array.  The size has to be determined by the number of numbers in the file.

I may be able to use an Arraylist somehow, but I don't have the skill to guarantee success.  Most of the issue here is that I have very little skill.  That's why I need the solution to be as dumbed down as possible.

The full details of the assignment:

A local high school is giving a standardized test to all of its students.  There are 50 questions on the test and the school would like you to gather some statistics on how the students performed.  Scores can range anywhere from 0 to 50.  All the scores are stored in a file (scores.txt) that you will need to download.

Input the data from the file and store the data into an array.  To do this, you will have to have your program open the data file, count the number of elements in the file, close the file, initialize your array, reopen the file and load the data into the array.

Then calculate and output the following statistics: average score, the mode of the scores, and the highest/lowest score.  In addition, output a list of the scores and the number of students that received each score.   (Hint:  you may need to use additional arrays to store information.)

Your program should be written using methods and should be well documented internally and externally.  Your output should be displayed using Message boxes.

The contents of my main method so far:

```
  int size, index = 0;
  int[] testscores;
  String input, output;

  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert filename including extension.");

    File scores = new File(input);
    Scanner data = new Scanner(scores);

    while (data.hasNext() && index<testscores.length)
    {
        testscores[index] = data.nextInt();
        index++;
    }
```

I don't want to use arraylists as that adds a whole level of complexity I don't have the know-how to deal with.  I need to know how I am to construct the array using the code I have setup here.  I assumed the while loop was supposed to build the array, but I need to initialize the array before hand which makes no sense.  I have two variables that I intend to make use of later on if need be.  Size can be used if I need to add something else to the main method to create a concrete size from reading the file (which is what I thought the loop would do).  I swear the class I'm taking doesn't give me the resources to do this stuff.  How hard is it to use a single line of code to get Java to do something so simple?  There should be a simple scanner method to accomplish all of this at once.

Here is where I am at now:

```
  int size = 0, index = 0;
  int[] testscores = new int[size];
  String input, output;

  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert filename including extension.");

    File scores = new File(input);
    Scanner data = new Scanner(scores);

    while (data.hasNext())
    {
        size++;
    }

  while (data.hasNext())
    {
        testscores[index]   = data.nextInt();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, testscores[index]);
        index++;
    }
  data.close();
```

This should return a lot of windows with an array entry in each, but the program hangs.  I was hoping this code would function so I could determine that the loops work, but even if they did work, my program wouldn't be doable without editing the second loop all over again anyway.

Comment: Please be more precise about the restrictions you're working under. If you can use more dynamic structures such as ArrayLists, then there are much better answers available to you than you'd have if you're limited to arrays.

Comment: My post now includes an edit on arraylists and the full details of my assignment.

Comment: Is there really no one who can help me with this? It's due by the end of the day. My instructor isn't responding. My classmates haven't posted anything I can use. I can't find anything on the internet to do this. My loops aren't functioning for whatever reason. Is there anyone who can pull this off?

Comment: The Scanner will only read through the file once. You need to create a new Scanner on the file to read it a second time. Notice that data.hasNext can never return true in the second while loop, because if it were returning true, you'd still be in the first loop.

Comment: @JonKiparsky I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: There are a number of errors in your code that are more about basic programming. For example, the size of your testscores array is zero, you don't seem to reset index the second time you go through the file, etc. These don't really relate to the problem at hand, they're just sloppy programming.

Comment: @JonKiparsky The size of my array is determined by the first loop.  Index is increased with each iteration of the loop.  I don't see where the problem is.  (Also, my code looks more organized in jGrasp than when I copy and paste it here.)

Comment: As I say, the problems now are basic debugging, and this is not the place for hand-holding of that sort. If you give more attention to doing the debugging and less to trying to get me to do it for you, I think we'll both be happier in the long run. Good luck - I think you can do it.

Comment: @JonKiparsky Apparently, the bigger problem is that I see nothing wrong with a program that someone else sees everything wrong with.  I honestly see a flawless program here.  How am I to correct something that looks perfect?

Comment: @JonKiparsky  Other threads have people chomping at the bit to edit other people's code.  I ask a question while in dire straits and no one is willing to follow through with assistance.  If you think there's a problem how about helping me with it?  How am I supposed to fix alleged issues if I don;t know what the problem is?

P.S. At least roywasse did what they could.  You on the other hand seem to think you have the answers to the problems you perceive but refuse to help me further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer a part of your question. You should use an ArrayList instead of an Array. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

An ArrayList doesn't have a fixed size, an Array does after its initial declaration.

Comment: Clearly an ArrayList is the correct construct for this application, but it looks like the OP's assignment specifies arrays.

Comment: I don't believe it matters which I use, but I will be creating methods to generate statistics in a plain text message dialog window.

Comment: Well, since java.util was in the game, I thought I should mention it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to do this would be to use a Scanner to read the lines of the file, and just count them. Assume that the number of lines (less any known header information) is the number of entries, and declare an array of that length. Then read the lines of the file again, using the nextDouble method to take each item as a number, and store it in the array at the appropriate location.

This is obviously not ideal, since it requires you to read the file from disk twice, but it might be the simplest for you to implement, and it surely uses only language constructs that you're allowed to use.

EDIT: If you're allowed to use ArrayLists, it's much easier. Create an ArrayList of Doubles. Open a Scanner on the file, and use a while loop to read the file - use the scanner's hasNextDouble method as the loop condition. In the body of the loop, use the scanner's nextDouble method to get a number, and use the ArrayList's add() method to insert it in the list. See the ArrayList [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for details on creating and adding to ArrayLists.

Note that you will have to use the Double wrapper class, since ArrayLists cannot contain primitives. However, autoboxing will take care of much of this for you.

Comment: The scores might not be on individual lines.  I can't assume that they will be.

Comment: In that case, I'll try to offer a better answer once I have a better idea of what restrictions you're working under.

Comment: My restrictions really only boil down to me being incompetent.

Comment: Hardly that. Merely ignorant, and ignorant is curable. See my edited answer.